# Javascript, creating an element in an array and setting a property to the new element

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm working on a problem for school and am confused on how to approach it. They want me to create an HTML  element AND(bolded in text) add a property to it. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code and the question.

Here is my code and the question.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AOOy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhPO.png)

Comment: Is it not just `h3.templeName = somevalue` this is how you set an element property like `h3.style.fontWeight = 'bold'` or any html element property

Comment: will that work if I have to create the html h3 element? or do I have to create the element then write that?

Comment: Relevant code etc should be included in the question.

Comment: You never say what actual problem you’re having or how you’ve attempted to solve it.

Comment: You can create the element, set its properties, and then append it to the document

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, maybe it will help

```
const listTemple = ['Temple A','Temple B','Temple C']
let element = ''
listTemple.forEach(temple => {
  element += `<h3 templeNames="${temple}" >${temple}</h3>`
})
document.querySelector('#yourElementId').innerHTML = element
```